# overlayed two images using html and css if I try any other overlay they are conflicting?

Tags: html, css

I have overlayed two images successfully but if I use the same thing for other    div images am getting conflict here is the jsfiddle code..
https://jsfiddle.net/cLew1t2v/ and here is code

```
<div >
    <div style="position:relative;">
         <img  src="http://getfreedeals.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/get-Toaster-worth-Rs.350-free-on-purchase-of-Rs.275-worth-of-frying-pan.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; ">
         <img  src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-9_zNrpUMkQo/VMDgzXMlX4I/AAAAAAAAAS8/HY4BkO70fB0/s1600/images.jpeg" style="position:absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px; z-index: 3;">

    </div>
</div>
 <div >
      <div  style="position:relative;">
         <img  src="http://getfreedeals.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/get-Toaster-worth-Rs.350-free-on-purchase-of-Rs.275-worth-of-frying-pan.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; ">
         <img  src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-9_zNrpUMkQo/VMDgzXMlX4I/AAAAAAAAAS8/HY4BkO70fB0/s1600/images.jpeg" style="position:absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px; z-index: 3;">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want the two overlayed images side by side but I am able to see them one above the other once can check my jsfiddle for live demo

Comment: Why are you used absolute position? Is there any purpose?

Comment: to position it relative to previous positioned div

Comment: I want the images to be like this find image in the url https://s16.postimg.org/gsxjpdyl1/Capture.jpg

Comment: yes thank you for help

Comment: its working for desktop but for mobile its again conflictig each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all selectors inside div with `position: relative` are positioned absolutely its height is 0.

You can set width and height to relative box and also float if you want to have inline elements.

```css
.relative-box{
  position:relative; 
  height: 350px; 
  width: 320px; 
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="relative-box">
             <img  src="http://getfreedeals.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/get-Toaster-worth-Rs.350-free-on-purchase-of-Rs.275-worth-of-frying-pan.jpg">
             <img  src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-9_zNrpUMkQo/VMDgzXMlX4I/AAAAAAAAAS8/HY4BkO70fB0/s1600/images.jpeg" style="position:absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px; z-index: 3;">
          
        </div>

          <div class="relative-box">
             <img  src="http://getfreedeals.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/get-Toaster-worth-Rs.350-free-on-purchase-of-Rs.275-worth-of-frying-pan.jpg" >
             <img  src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-9_zNrpUMkQo/VMDgzXMlX4I/AAAAAAAAAS8/HY4BkO70fB0/s1600/images.jpeg" style="position:absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px; z-index: 3;">
            
        </div>
```